not getting circular input switch primeng component

i am following the primeng documentation for InputSwitch component in which that component is circular but i am getting square kind of component
attaching the image

Code:
<p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="isOn" (onChange)="handleChange()" ></p-inputSwitch>


i am not able to find any border or rounded properties
we need to design the label staticaly ? there are not any label related props supporting


@NarenMurali : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ttztrz?

the provided stackblitz does not have the square toggle button, could you try replicating the issue and sharing back again, thanks!

the stackblitz which i have shared is mention in primeng , i write the exact same code

You are not using PrimeFaces

override the styles is works.
:host {
  ::ng-deep p-inputswitch .p-inputswitch-slider {
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
  ::ng-deep p-inputswitch .p-inputswitch-slider::before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}

